# How to edit/delete a Confluence page containing a redirect?

Tags: confluence

I want to edit (or delete) a Confluence page with a redirect macro in it, but I can't click on any action link before the page gets redirected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Copy the page URL
2. Paste the copied URL into the browser address bar
3. Append the query parameter `redirect=false` to the URL
4. Hit Enter/Return